# TypeError: Required argument not found __getitem__ numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, class, numpy

I aimed to prevent negative indexing in arrays.

```
import numpy as np

class Myarray (np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self,n):
       if n<0:
          raise IndexError("...")
       return np.ndarray.__getitem__(self,n)

class Items(Myarray):
    def __init__(self):
       self.load_tab()

class Item_I(Items):
    def load_tab(self):
       self.tab=np.load("file.txt")

a=Item_I()
```

When I create an instance I got an error:

```
in <module>
  a=Item_I()

TypeError: Required argument 'shape' (pos 1) not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you subclass from a class that uses `__new__` to create new instances and [`numpy.ndarray` requires several arguments in `__new__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) before it even attempts to call `__init__`:

> Parameters for the `__new__` method
>
> shape : tuple of ints
>
> ```
> Shape of created array.
> ```
>
> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> ```
> Any object that can be interpreted as a numpy data type.
> ```
>
> buffer : object exposing buffer interface, optional
>
> ```
> Used to fill the array with data.
> ```
>
> offset : int, optional
>
> ```
> Offset of array data in buffer.
> ```
>
> strides : tuple of ints, optional
>
> ```
> Strides of data in memory.
> ```
>
> order : {‘C’, ‘F’}, optional
>
> ```
> Row-major (C-style) or column-major (Fortran-style) order.
> ```

However the NumPy documentation contains a whole page for [Subclassing `ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

You probably should just use `view` and `Myarray` instead of subclassing from `Myarray`:

```
tab=np.load("file.txt")
tab.view(Myarray)
```